# Hibernate database (maria-db) change detect

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I need to understand, Is there anyway I can continuously look for change in Maria-DB table using Hibernate.

I have a spring boot application that is connected to Maria-DB. If some other application perform CURD on table, I want to catch that in spring.

If it's not possible using hibernate, suggest me alternative.

PS : This spring boot application is running is different Docker Container and Maria-DB is running is different Docker Container.

Comment: Neither Hibernate nor Maria-DB has support for change notifications.

Comment: Have a look at this lienk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630114/how-to-track-database-changes-dynamically-using-spring

Comment: @cralfaro According to my understanding, hibernate interceptor work with session. Means if we perform action on Entity for same application then it will work.In my case some other application is performing CURD operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this specific problem is Spring Integration module as other ways not working  here. I have create a sample application to demonstrate [here you can find the source code](https://github.com/Umair-Ansari/SpringIntegrationJDBCInboundPooler)

What this application does look database continuously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Database **Triggers**, or better why don't you try enabling Hibernates 2nd level cache?

Comment: As I have mentioned,  triggers will not work here because my db is in different docker container and my application is in different docker container. Plus Hibernate Caches are within applications and here in this scenario curd operation will be performed by another application and that application will be on different docker container.